# How to save base64 image in Blob with Carrierwave in Rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64, blob, carrierwave, data-uri

Like described in [this Tutorial](http://rohitrox.github.io/2013/07/19/canvas-images-and-rails/), I'm converting a canvas into a DataUrl and this DataUrl into a Blob. Then I make an ajax post request and would like to save the image in the Database using Carrierwave.

This is my JS code:

```
uploadButton.on('click', function(e) {

  var dataURL = mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64;");

  // Get our file
  var file= dataURLtoBlob(dataURL);

  // Create new form data
  var fd = new FormData();

  // Append our Canvas image file to the form data
  fd.append("image", file);

  // And send it
  $.ajax({
    url: "/steps",
    type: "POST",
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
  });
});

// Convert dataURL to Blob object
function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {

  // Decode the dataURL
  var binary = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]);

  // Create 8-bit unsigned array
  var array = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
    array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
  }

  // Return our Blob object
  return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});
}
```

When I add the following code to my controller, then the Image get's saved but of course not through carrierwave.

```
File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/somefilename.png", 'wb') do |f|
  f.write(params[:image].read)
end
```

**Updated Info:**

These are the params for my ajax post request:

```
Parameters: {"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007feac3e9a8a8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/0k/q3kc7bpx3_51kc_5d2r1gqcc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140211-1346-gj7kb7>, @original_filename="blob", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"blob\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}
```

And these are the params for a standard file upload:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "image"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007feac20c2e20 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/0k/q3kc7bpx3_51kc_5d2r1gqcc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140211-1346-1ui8wq1>, @original_filename="burger.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[image]\"; filename=\"xy.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}
```

If I do `Image.create(params[:image])` I have transaction rollback...

**Error for transaction rollback:**

```
Unprocessable Entity
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: image You are not allowed to upload "" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png)
```

Comment: And what happens if you assign `params[:image]` to a carrierwave-mounted attribute?

Comment: So I made `Image.create(image: params[:image])` but it rolls back the transaction...

Comment: What error is causing it to roll back?  You can use `Image.create!(...)` (with an exclamation point) to force the exception to be raised.  The only major difference I can see from your post is that the upload file is missing an extension (named 'blob').  You can probably fix this by appending `.png` to the filename (and original_filename) before passing it to the `create` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are whitelisting the filetypes permitted.  By default, Carrierwave will attempt to determine the filetype by the filename extension - which isn't being passed since this is actually a Blob object.  As such, you're getting a validation error about the file's 'type'.  To fix this, simply append the expected filename extension for blob objects:

```
if params[:image].try(:original_filename) == 'blob'
  params[:image].original_filename << '.png'
end

Image.create!(image: params[:image])
```

Comment: just implemented this myself. This was so great. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I just wanted to add, you can add the file type in your view while appending your blob.

```
  // Get our file
  var file = dataURLtoBlob(dataURL);

  // Create new form data
  var fd = new FormData();

  // Append our Canvas image file to the form data
  fd.append("image", file, "blob.jpg");
```

Note the ending when we define the filename.
Hope this helps someone.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append